# Cannot load image "./darknet/dataset/z115.jpg" STB Reason: can't fopen

Tags: yolo

I am training Darknet YOLO-V3 on a Google cloud, VM instance to detect the custom object.

The darknet directory contains the following:

- dataset directory: It includes all the annotated data.
  [Annotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrtIT.png)
- obj.data file: It contains
  [Obj data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrdNG.png)
- obj.names file: It contains
  [obj names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0QGQ.png)
- train.txt file: It contains
  [train text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbOe.png)

When I am runing this command:
./darknet detector train obj.data yolov3-tiny.cfg darknet53.conv.74

The Error is generated:
Cannot load image "./darknet/dataset/z115.jpg" STB Reason: can't fopen

Comment: try to use full path

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am getting the same issue while testing

Comment: it can be filesystem related, it really means "Can't fopen"